# Excel Data Inaccuracies (String conversions)

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Currently I am referencing a set of values via the SUMPRODUCT statement below (not yet completed)

```
SUMPRODUCT(--('[FY16 GBU Master Data File.xlsx]Fuel Proportions Act'!$B$30:$B$34="Coal")*--('[FY16 GBU Master Data File.xlsx]Fuel Proportions Act'!$D$2:$O$2>=IS!D30))
```

$D$2 to $O$2 refers to the following date range:
2015/Jul .... 2016/Jun

The first part of my sum returns the following:

```
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

This tells me that the first part is fine - we have found our match for "Coal".

The second part of my sum product returns the following:

```
1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
```

For some reason, in the date conversion, 2 month's are not parsed correctly.
I cannot understand why this is the case as this has worked previously without any errors. Would anyone be able to point out why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the values in `'[FY16 GBU Master Data File.xlsx]Fuel Proportions Act'!$D$2:$O$2` are the ***text*** values

```
2015/Jul   2015/Aug   2015/Sep  2015/Okt   2015/Nov   2015/Dez   2016/Jan   2016/Feb   2016/Mrz   2016/Apr   2016/Mai   2016/Jun
```

and `IS!D30` is the ***text*** value `2015/Feb`.

With string comparison `2015/Aug` < `2015/Feb` because `A` is lower than `F` and `2015/Dez` < `2015/Feb` because `D` is lower than `F`.

You should not compare ***text*** values but ***date*** values. You can format the date values as `YYYY/MMM`.

Comment: Hi Axel, thanks for that. I made a misconception re: SUMPRODUCT, I assumed that where you select the date is significant (i.e. There was a Jul-15...etc) below I could select but I thought I couldn't do this as the date range is below what I thought I could use. However I realize now that was irrelevant so I have now compared date values with date values rather than textual conversions.

Thanks though! :)